# Redirect second form at that time first form is minimized in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have two form,form1 and form2 in C# desktop application.Form1 is for inserting data in to database.And Form2 is for showing data into Grid view.And form2 contain two buttons Edit and Delete.

Now my problem is when i click on edit button that time i wants redirect on form1 and edit item and it will be done but  when i am redirecting on form1 at that time form1 is automatically minimized.

So all the time i have open or maximized form1.

Please give me some advice how i solve minimization problem?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a matter of calling Form.Hide(), Form.Show(), and Form.BringToFront() when you want them to be hidden, shown, or brought to the front of the z-order.

Comment: :Thank for giving advice but it will not working.actually i redirect on form1 successfully.But when i redirect form1 at that time form1 is open and minimized.So all time i click on maximize button to open form.And i wants direct focus on form1.

Comment: :hello please give me replay as soon as posible

Comment: @Mansinh I am going to need to see some code to help any more.